# Proving uniform continuity by definition

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-continuity

Here is the question:
Use the definition of uniform continuity to prove $f(x)=x^2 + 2x - 5$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,3]$.

I need help understanding how this works, and solving these types of problems in general that specify intervals.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|f'(x)| = |2x+2| \leq 2|x|+2 \leq 2\cdot 3+2 = 8$. Thus by MVT: $|f(x)-f(y)| = |f'(c)(x-y)| \leq 8|x-y|$. Can you take it from here?.

**Method** $2$:

$|f(x)-f(y)| = |x^2+2x-5 - (y^2+2y-5)| = |x-y||x+y+2|\leq (|x|+|y|+|2|)|x-y| \leq (3+3+2)|x-y| = 8|x-y|$. And you can go from here as well.

Comment: Thank you for your help BRICS. Unfortunately, I'm not using MVT yet. How else could this type of problem be solved?

Comment: Thank you for both contributions. If I understand this correctly, you are using the UC definition and then the triangle inequality, but what I don't understand is why $(|x|+|y|+|2|)|x-y| \leq (3+3+2)|x-y|$ why did you pick 3 for x and y?

Comment: Since $x \in [0,3] \Rightarrow 0 \leq x \leq 3 \Rightarrow |x| \leq 3$.